How do I construct an object with temporary inputs with python's dataclasses?
I have a question about best practices when it comes to python dataclasses. The dataclass structure. Is it OK practice to delete temporary class attributes, or am I better off foregoing the dataclass entirely?
I want to use the attribute IOMap (name suggestions welcome) to represent the flow through a factory, where the inputs have a negative rate and the outputs have a positive rate. However, I know that my users will probably be thinking in terms of inputs and outputs, so I want to give them the option to construct the class that way.
There are two ways to do this. This is the traditional approach:
class Factory(Building):
    def __init__(self,
                *,
                id: str,
                name: str,
                power: int,
                size: int,
                inputs: Dict[Material, float] = None,
                outputs: Dict[Material, float] = None,
                IOMap: Dict[Material, float] = None,
    ):
        super().__init__(id, name, power, size)
        
        if IOMap is not None:
            if inputs is not None or outputs is not None:
                raise ValueError("IOMap cannot be used with inputs or outputs.")
            self.IOMap = IOMap
        else:
            if inputs is None or outputs is None:
                raise ValueError("inputs and outputs must be provided if IOMap is not.")
            self.IOMap = outputs
            for material, rate in inputs.items():
                self.IOMap[material] = self.IOMap.get(material, 0) - rate

And this is the dataclass approach:
@dataclass
class Factory(Building):
    inputs: Optional[Dict[Material, float]] = None
    outputs: Optional[Dict[Material, float]] = None
    IOMap: Optional[Dict[Material, float]] = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if IOMap is not None:
            if inputs is not None or outputs is not None:
                raise ValueError("IOMap cannot be used with inputs or outputs.")
            self.IOMap = IOMap
        else:
            if inputs is None or outputs is None:
                raise ValueError("inputs and outputs must be provided if IOMap is not.")
            self.IOMap = outputs
            for material, rate in inputs.items():
                self.IOMap[material] = self.IOMap.get(material, 0) - rate
        del self.inputs
        del self.outputs

I like this much better, but deleing them in this way just feels... wrong.
I don't want inputs and outputs to be class attributes. Since IOMap will be used exclusively for internal processes, I don't want users thinking that they can use inputs and outputs at all.
I would love to continue to use dataclasses, since Factory is the parent of many children, and it would be amazing not to have to write a monstrous __init__ function for every one.
tldr; Is it worth deleting class attributes to continue to use dataclasses, or is it better to move to a traditional class?

I have a really dumb question here. When you say "factory" and "Building" are you talking about the actual, physical, real-world objects?

Yes haha. I realize that might have been confusing when talking about typical inheritance stuff

Ok, so your intended method of deleting class attributes means that if you run out of stock, your warehouse blows up because it can never take any more stock again. And your code blows up

you are missing all the self.

Much nerdier. This is actually a pet project for the Factorio-style game Mindustry. I'm creating a module to help speed up calculating how many of each kind of factory I need to have enough resource flow for the ones I want. input/output/IOMap represent rates, not quantities (i.e. {TITANIUM: 0.5} means 0.5 titanium per second). These rates never change, so I'm never going to update them.
If you feel like this context would be helpful, I can edit my post. My main question was on the idea of deleting attributes, so I didn't want to clutter it with the rest of the project design. :)

@DiegoTorresMilano Where am I missing the self.? I'm pretty sure I included it where it should be, but I could be wrong.

Not really much nerdier. I've spent a lot of time in industrial optimisation. You will gain nothing but headaches if you start deleting attributes. This is a disaster waiting to happen in your code. If you want to have global constants, do that, and pull them out of the class. But don't delete class attributes. If you want to speed things up, find a way to abstract your calcs into numpy or something

So it seems like you're telling me to go with the first option then, correct? (The custom init method never creates them in the first place). That's how I have it now.
Followup question: with python dataclasses, can dataclasses inherit from normal classes? I've enjoyed working with the syntax, and this Factory class has a lot of children that I'd rather not write the long init functions for.

Yes, go with the first approach out of the two

Hmm... It seems to me that you need a factory (not the facility, the design pattern). Use a factory method to create your instance, in which you can pass all you alternative creation parameters, while the actual class only have the canonical ones. After object creation, the factory parameters are gone. No deletions, no leftovers.

A few options that I can think of for your case. They are not sorted in any specific order, but have in mind that "Simple is better than complex".

Have setter a method.
Only IOMaps would exist in your dataclass, and client can use inputs and outputs to set IOMaps via a specialized method, that encapsulates the setting logic. You should make IOMaps a keyword-only parameter, so it will not mess up your Factory subclasses constructors.

Expose a inputs/outputs to IOMap function
Use this if you don't mind clients being fully aware of the IOMap object, so they can explicitly set its value with a function that converts and apply the right logic.

Use a factory method.
So, you want clients to pass some parameters that are only useful for convenient object construction, but are not real attributes of the object's type? That is what Factory Pattern was invented for. In this case, just a simple @classmethod would do the job.

Create a factory class.
If you sense the complexity of the alternative creators will increase, like if you need to support several construction methods with different parameters, you could end up needing to move the factory pattern to a class. It is a bit awkward to handle subclassing, but what I do in cases like this is to pass the ultimate class as a parameter to the factory creator method.


Sample implementations:
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

# assuming Material is hashable, as it is used as dictionary key
@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True) 
class Material:
    name: str

# assuming all the other attributes come from a parent class
@dataclass
class Building:
    id: str
    name: str
    power: int
    size: int

# only ioMap is an actual attribute
@dataclass
class Factory(Building):
    ioMap: dict[Material, float] = field(default_factory=dict, kw_only=True)

    # for solution 1
    def with_ios(self, inputs, outputs):
        self.ioMap = Factory.ios_to_ioMap(inputs, outputs)
        return self
    
    # for solution 2 (with whatever is your actual update logic)
    @staticmethod
    def ios_to_ioMap(inputs, outputs):
        ioMap = {}
        for material in {*inputs, *outputs}:
            ioMap[material] = outputs.get(material, 0) - inputs.get(material, 0)
        return ioMap

    # for solution 3
    @classmethod
    def create_with_ios(cls, *args, inputs, outputs, **kwargs):
        return cls(*args, **kwargs).with_ios(inputs, outputs)


# let's see how to handle subclassing
@dataclass
class ChocolateFactory(Factory):
    oompaloompas: int


# for solution 4
@dataclass
class FactoryCreator:
    id: str
    name: str
    power: int
    size: int
    inputs: dict[Material, float]
    outputs: dict[Material, float]

    def create(self, asType=Factory, *args, **kwargs):
        return asType(self.id, self.name, self.power, self.size, *args, **kwargs).with_ios(self.inputs, self.outputs)

Usage:
id, name, power, size = "id", "name", 100, 10
oompaloompas = 999
inputs = {Material("milk"): 3.5, Material("cocoa"): 1.5, Material("energy"): 5}
outputs = {Material("energy"): 1, Material("bars"): 10}

# solution 1: 
s1 = ChocolateFactory(id, name, power, size, oompaloompas).with_ios(inputs, outputs)

# solution 2: 
s2 = ChocolateFactory(id, name, power, size, oompaloompas)
s2.ioMap = Factory.ios_to_ioMap(inputs, outputs)

# solution 3: 
s3 = ChocolateFactory.create_with_ios(id, name, power, size, oompaloompas, inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# solution 4: 
s4 = FactoryCreator(id, name, power, size, inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs).create(ChocolateFactory, oompaloompas)

